# What is a SignalR Hub and how can it be renamed?

Tags: javascript, signalr, azure-functions, signalr-hub

In my Azure Function I define a `hubName` but I can't seem to find any documentation what this actually is and how I can change it. If I change it from the default `"chat"` in my function it doesn't work anymore but where is it defined anyway?

```
{
  "disabled": false,
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "type": "signalRConnectionInfo",
      "name": "connectionInfo",
      "userId": "{userId}",
      "hubName": ????,   <------------------------------------------
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SignalR Hubs are a way to logically group connections as [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-concept-serverless-development-config#signalr-hubs).

Take an example of a chat application. A group of users could be part of the same hub which allows for sending messages between users in the group.

The `hubName` here can be any string which is used to scope messages being sent between clients. All of your clients would have to connect to the same hub to be able to see messages being sent.

Comment: How would I change the hub?

Comment: For a dynamic hub name, you can use [binding expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns). In your case, using a [route parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook?tabs=javascript#using-route-parameters) would be ideal I suppose.